# Going back up a line in psql shell

Tags: psql

Does anyone know a short cut to going back up a line in psql? I've tried ending with ); and then hitting the up arrow. I can retrieve the line of code that I want and then correct it, but then what? The initial mistake prevented me from CREATING A TABLE, so do I recreate the remaining lines of code from this point forward to finish creating the table.  I'm trying to avoid retyping 10 lines of information. I'm using the postgres database and the instructor accomplishing this with very little effort; however, I cannot see the commands he is using to recreate several lines of text which a appear to use only one key.  If you look at 52:00 - 53:00 on the instructional video timeline you will see what I mean.  After he ends the code with ); He immediately recreates the previous block of code.  How does he do this?

[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw--VYLpxG4)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qw--VYLpxG4

Answer (score 0):

They just cut out parts of the video. No big magic there.

But you could use `\e` to start your default editor containing the last command you sent.  That may be the most efficient way to do this.